# How to segment Google AdWordsAPI Ad_Performance_Report?

Tags: python, google-api, google-ads-api

I am new to Google AdWords API.

Right now I am downloading the `AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` and I want to segment it by day, but I cant find the right example in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting#segmentation)

My code looks like this:

```
def get_data(customer_id):
    df = None
    for item in customer_id:
        report_query = (adwords.ReportQueryBuilder()
                        .Select('AdGroupId', 'AdGroupName', 'AbsoluteTopImpressionPercentage', 'Impressions', 'Conversions')
                        .From('AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT')
                        .During('LAST_7_DAYS')
                        .Build())

        # You can provide a file object to write the output to. For this
        # demonstration we use sys.stdout to write the report to the screen.
        report_downloader.DownloadReportWithAwql(
            report_query,
            'CSV',
            output,
            client_customer_id=item,  # denotes which adw account to pull from
            skip_report_header=True,
            skip_column_header=False,
            skip_report_summary=True,
            include_zero_impressions=False)

        output.seek(0)
        df = pd.read_csv(output)
        if df is None:
            df = pd.DataFrame(output)
        else:
            df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(output))
    return df
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `Date` to your field list (i.e. the `Select` clause of your query).

As mentioned in the [report's documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/ad-performance-report#date), `Date` is a field with behavior "Segment", so adding it to the returned fields will result in a segmented report.